# simple asp.net tag helper list<> question

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I am not sure if you can even do this, I am just learning and experimenting some.

In a cshtml file I have:

```
@{ 
List<string> items = new List<string>();
items.Add("item 1");
items.Add("item2");
```

}

Then I want to just access that in a select:

```
            <td><select asp-for="Genre" asp-items=@items /></td>
```

Is there a way to do this or I am just trying to feed a baseball to a horse who really wants an apple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `List<SelectListItem>` instead of `List<string>`

The `SelectListItem` class belongs to `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering` namespace.

```
@{ 

    List<SelectListItem> items= new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem {Text = "item1", Value = "item1"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "item2", Value = "item2"}
    };
}

<td><select asp-for="Genre" asp-items="@items"></select></td>
```

Comment: I get the same error (which I should have posted) of Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>'

Comment: That works and makes sense.  Thank you, I appreciate it.  I will accept it when SOF lets me...